# Como adicionar 1 quilômetro a uma coordenada Google Maps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

Como poderia adicionar 1 km (ou mil metros) a uma coordenada google maps para determinar uma área?

Exemplo:

Raio formado pelos pontos A e B:

Ponto A = Latitude:-22.91009, Longetude: -43.107499.

Ponto B = Latitude(A)+VALOR, Longetude(B)+VALOR.

Porém a distância de A até B seria em quilômetros ou metros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supondo que você calculasse o raio pelo teorema de Pitágoras, não seria em quilômetros nem metros e sim em graus. Nesse caso você teria que fazer a diferença entre as latitudes de A e B e a diferença entre as longitudes de A e B. Se a distância latitudinal entre A e B fosse 10° e a distância longitudinal fosse 30°, pelo teorema de Pitágoras teríamos:

> 10^2 + 30^2 = X^2 => √¯ 10^2 + 30^2 = 31,62

Considerando que 1° de latitude são cerca de 110 km e 1° de longitude varia de 110 km na linha do equador a 0 km nos pólos [*1](http://www.mat.ufrgs.br/~portosil/passa2d.html) e supondo que você estivesse na linha do equador, o raio seria de 3478 km.

Comment: sua resposta é muito boa, mas fiz umas pesquisas e vou complementar ela!! Me ajudou a entender alguns pontos!! Obrigado

Comment: faltou complementar ela aqui @TiagoAmaral